# Iterate array to obtain a value.

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I have a field that returns a result in JSON format.

```
$('#selectCategory').on('change', function () {
    var optionSelect = $(this).val();
    console.log('The option selected is: ' + optionSelect);
    $.post("{{path('playlist_category') }}", {category: optionSelect}, 
         function (filterContent) {
             console.log(filterContent);
         }, 'json');
});
```

The filterContent function returns a result similar to this:

[image: console result]

But I just want to stay with the relevant information to the 'id' of the element.

If I do the following , the console returns something like this:

```
function (filterContent) {
    for (var content in filterContent.category_result) {
        for (var data in filterContent.category_result[content]) {
            var result = filterContent.category_result[content][data];
                console.log(result);
        }
    }
}, 'json');
```

[image: Console result 2]

How could obtain only the data 'id'?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No need of the inner for-in loop use like this

```
function (filterContent) {
    for (var content in filterContent.category_result) {
        console.log(filterContent.category_result[content].id)

    }
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 1):

Use this code instead:

```
$.post("{{path('playlist_category') }}", {category: optionSelect}, 
   function (filterContent) {
      for(var i = 0; i < filterContent.category_result.length; i++) {
         console.log('id', filterContent.category_result[i]['id']);
      }
   }
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to make result as a JSON. I am trying to tweak your function(filterContent)

```
function (filterContent) {
var result={};
    for (var content in filterContent.category_result) {
        for (var data in filterContent.category_result[content]) {
            result.id = filterContent.category_result[content][id];
            result.data= filterContent.category_result[content][data];
                console.log(result);
        }
    }
}, 'json');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this to get an array of the ids:

```
function (filterContent) {
  var ids =  $(filterContent.category_result).map(function() { return this.id }); 
}
```

Comment: This answer is incomplete, syntactically wrong, and you don't need to use jQuery to perform a map.

Comment: @Mike C Browser compatibility IE9+ without using jquery for map.  Why do you think it is syntactically wrong? Incomplete? What do you think the guy will do in real - he will print the output in the console or he will want to collect the ids? I can bet his idea is to collect the ids instead of print in the console.

Comment: The function lacks a name nor is it a property in another object. You gather the IDs then do nothing with them.

Comment: the funcation is an AJAX success handler and needs no name... I won't continue because these are besic things ... but one think you are right ... ids shoud be declared outside the body ... or assigned further ... but I have no idea what the guy will do when he got the ids ... anyway it is a general concept, not a typical solution, showing he can use map to map a collection to another collection.

Comment: I don't know why I never noticed it was a callback. My bad... That's what I get for jumping the gun instead of looking at the context.